# Python Pandas for Creating CSVs and Memory Usage

Tags: python, pandas

I have the below which will just parse text files containing json objects and then convert to a dataframe before saving to disk as csv. I'm trying to figure out if this is the most memory efficient way and what is gradually using up my memory as this runs against around 200 different files with each file being saved as 1-10M lines each. I'm noticing that it ends up using up more than 50GB of my memory by the time it completes. More specifically, is using Pandas and Dataframes the best choice if I don't care about doing any analysis but only transforming the data into csv and is there a different implementation that would not degrade my memory?

```
def readfiles(pattern, sourcefile):
    #iterate through all zip files in datadir and yield trigger data
    try:
        with zipfile.ZipFile(sourcefile, 'r') as myzip:
            for logfile in myzip.namelist():
                for line in myzip.open(logfile):
                    try:
                        line = ujson.loads(line.rstrip('\n').rstrip(','))
                        if pattern in line:
                            for i in line['key1']:
                                yield i, line['key2']['key3'],\
                            line['key4']['key5'],line['key6'],\
                            line['key7']['key8'],line['key9']['key10']
                    except ValueError as err:
                        pass
    except zipfile.error, e:
        pass

def convertdfcsv(lines, filename):
    """Consumer for readfiles function that saves dataframe as csv."""

    df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(lines)
    #return df
    df.to_csv(os.path.join(triggertempdir, filename), index=False, header=None)
    print("Completed Processing {}".format(filename))

def main(pattern, min_date, max_date):
    """Main function to initiate pipeline"""
    sourcezipfiles = retrieve_from_s3(date)
    lines = readfiles(pattern, i)
    csvout = '{}.csv'.format(i[:-4])
    convertdfcsv(lines, csvout)
```

Comment: At least for JSON readers(/writers), most of them are known to seriously leak memory, so best to run as a separate Python `multiprocessing.Process` with `multiprocessing.Pipe(duplex=True)` where you send it the filename, and it sends you a stream of records (don't try to send all the records in one giant message). This is my strong recommendation from having tried unsuccesfully to debug and eliminate memory leaks with most of the popular json parsers. Easier to circumvent the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would just use command line tools eg [jq](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Invokingjq), or json2csv, but I haven't understood your parsing.

here is an example that will extract key1 and key2 and output as comma separated:
jq -r '[.key1,.key2]|@csv'